# Property 'x' does not exist on type 'typeof Socket' although I have it declared

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

This is my class.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class Socket {

  public isConnected: boolean = false;

  constructor(public events: Events) {
    console.log("Socket.js constructed.");
  }
}
```

I'm using it like:

```
import { Socket } from '../App/Socket/Socket';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'layout.html'
})
export class ConferenceApp {
    constructor() {
        console.log(Socket.isConnected);
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting `Property 'isConnected' does not exist on type 'typeof Socket'` error when I run ionic serve.

Typescript doesn't support values to be attached on class scope?

Thank you.

Comment: share code of `../App/Socket/Socket` ? is `../App/Socket/Socket` is `service` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you use it here

```ts
console.log(Socket.isConnected);
```

`isConnected` would need to be a static property instead of the instance property you created.

I assume you want to use it differently anyway because you added `@Injectable()`.

You need to provide the service somewhere to be able to get it injected.
I don't know if `NgModule` landed already in ionic, but you can also provide it at the component if it doesn't need to be shared with other components.

To inject it, add it to the constructor parameter list

```ts
import { Socket } from '../App/Socket/Socket';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'layout.html',
  providers: [Socket]
})
export class ConferenceApp {
    constructor(socket:Socket) {
        console.log(socket.isConnected);
    }
}
```

then access it using the constructor parameter instead of the class name.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance of `Socket` by `new Socket()`. Then you will be able to access the property. You can also inject it via Dependency Injection.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're using Socket as a `static` class rather than using the DI system of angular2.

This will work:

```
import { Socket } from '../App/Socket/Socket';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'layout.html'
})
export class ConferenceApp {
    constructor(socket:Socket) {
        console.log(socket.isConnected);
    }
}
```

Because it's using the DI system of angular2, you'll receive an instance of Socket, not the actual `Socket` class.